# Are there any memory layout docs for ARM64?

Tags: arm, arm64

Is there any reference material for where various images should be loaded on ARM-A (aarch64) architectures? For instance, is there anything that says where in memory a bootloader should be placed, where the hypervisor should start, or where trustzone should begin?

Comment: It is vendor dependant.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

The closest reference for this would be [SBSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Base_System_Architecture), however:

> Note: Compliant software must not make any assumptions about the
>   memory map that might prejudice compliant hardware. For example, the
>   full physical address space must be supported. There must be no
>   dependence on memory or peripherals being located at certain physical
>   locations